# No Java support on Firefox

Tags: firefox

I have this IP printer that uses some java-applet to get it's work done, yet as of a few days ago, Firefox dropped all support for npapi plugins but flash, hence java is no longer supported.... They have claimed to release some new distribution that would have extended support for java users... yet apparently this doesn't work for me.... any idea how to solve this and allow java support by my browser?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely should have Googled ["Java support in Firefox"](https://www.google.com/search?q=Java%20support%20in%20Firefox&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab). The result is promising:

> ### Firefox 52 and above
>
> Beginning with Firefox 52 (released March 2017), plug-in support is limited to Adobe Flash, and drops support for NPAPI, impacting plugins for Java, Silverlight, and other similar NPAPI based plugins.
>
> If you have problems accessing Java applications using Firefox, Oracle recommends using Internet Explorer (Windows) or Safari (Mac OS X) instead. Developers and System administrators looking for alternative ways to support Firefox users should see this blog regarding [Launching Web Start applications](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/launching_web_start_applications).
>
> ### Firefox 52 ESR 32-bit release
>
> Mozilla offers an [Extended Support Release (ESR)](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/organizations/) version of Firefox specifically for use by organizations who need extended support for mass deployments. Only Mozilla Firefox 52 ESR 32-bit release will continue offering support for the standards-based plugin support technology required to launch Java Applets. To see if you are using an ESR release, check the Firefox menu item (Help -> About) and looking for the "ESR" identifier.
>
> Mozilla maintains Firefox ESR Releases for approximately one year. Developers and users still relying on the Java plugin technology in the 32-bit Mozilla Firefox web browser should consider migrating to a different solution.
>
> ---
>
> **Source:** "[Java plug-in does not work in Firefox after installing Java](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/firefox_java.xml)". *Java.com*. Oracle. March 2017.

You can visit the source for more goodies; I just copied and pasted the critical part. After all I must be mindful of the fair use laws too.